# Scala: Printing a Binary Tree That's a Class

Tags: scala

Hello I am new to Scala and I'm having a hard time getting my class to print some values out.

```
class TreeDemo[T](implicit o : T => Ordered[T]) {

      sealed trait BinaryTree
      case object Empty extends BinaryTree
      case class Node(left:BinaryTree, d:T, right:BinaryTree) extends BinaryTree


      // construct a "leaf" node
      def Leaf(d : T) : BinaryTree = Node(Empty,d,Empty)

      // remove all nodes equal to x from tree t
      def remove(t : BinaryTree, x : T) : BinaryTree = {
        replace(t, x, Empty)
      }

      val myTree = Node(Node(Leaf(1),2,Leaf(3)),4,Leaf(5))
      val x = remove(myTree, 2)

      def main (args: Array[String]) {
       println(x)
      }
}
```

From the code above I am trying to print the remove def but I am getting errors.

Comment: Please define `but I am getting errors`.

Comment: `remove()` hasn't been defined in the posted code. And class `TreeDemo` _receives_ the type parameter `T`, so it is defined outside of the class, therefore you can't create a `Leaf(1)` (where `T` is `Int`) inside of the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want remove to remove nodes in place from the tree, then you will want `var` values. I was not sure because `replace` is missing from your snippet
- As comments point out, `Node` can only take `T` until you instantiate an actual `TreeDemo`, so at the time of definition of the class, you cannot create Nodes of specific types, such as `Leaf(1)` etc. because it would be a type mismatch.
- It seems the type variable should be on BinaryTree itself, since you want your demo to try out specific trees, and it can be covariant (`+T`) to allow for `Empty` to be any other valid BinaryTree.

  - Left and right trees of a node should have the same types as the node.
- You can override `toString` to allow for more informative printing
- A method called `main` inside of a class doesn't serve as an entry-point. In Java, only a `static void main` will serve as an application entry-point. In Scala, `main` should also be in static (in an object instead of a class) in order to run.

```scala
sealed trait BinaryTree[+T]
case object Empty extends BinaryTree[Nothing]
class Node[T](var left:BinaryTree[T], var d:T, var right:BinaryTree[T])(implicit val ordering: Ordering[T]) extends BinaryTree[T] {
  override def toString: String = (left, right) match {
    case (Empty, Empty) => s"(${d})"
    case (Empty, right) => s"(${left},${d})"
    case (left, Empty) => s"(${d}, ${right})"
    case _ => s"(${left}, ${d}, ${right})"
  }
}
object Node{
  // define remove here (if static) or in the class
  def apply[T:Ordering](t: T) = new Node[T](Empty, t, Empty)
  def apply[T:Ordering](left:BinaryTree[T], t: T) = new Node[T](left, t, Empty)
  def apply[T:Ordering](left:BinaryTree[T], t: T, right:BinaryTree[T]) = new Node[T](left, t, right)
  def apply[T:Ordering](t: T, right:BinaryTree[T]) = new Node[T](Empty, t, right)
}
// either extend App, or have a main method, but use an object 
object TreeApp extends App {
  val myTree = Node(Node(Node(1),2,Node(3)),4,Node(5))
  println(myTree)
}
```